# Convergence of moment of functional of random variable

Tags: expected-value, convergence, moments, function

Define $X_n$ a continuous random variable that converges in distribution to $X$. Morever, we know that $E[|X_n|^p] \rightarrow E[|X|^p]$ for some $p > 0$.

Then, could we prove that for any continuous function $f$

$$E[|f(X_n)|^p] \rightarrow E[|f(X)|^p]?$$

Or which additional assumptions do we need? Or if $X_n$ is uniformly integrable does it imply that $f(X_n)$ is as well U.I ?

Comment: The limit you ask about doesn't even need to be defined, because all the expectations involved could be infinite.  Consider, for instance, distributions with finite absolute $p$ moments but infinite absolute $2p$ moments and let $f(x)=x^2.$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.  Set the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ to be $((0, 1], \mathscr{B}, \lambda)$ and define $X_n = \sqrt{n}I_{(0, n^{-1})}(x)$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, $X \equiv 0$, then
\begin{align}
E[|X_n|] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0 = E[|X|]
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.

Let $f(x) = x^2$, which is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(X_n) = nI_{(0, n^{-1})}(x)$, $f(X) = 0$, hence
\begin{align}
E[|f(X_n)|] = 1 \not\to 0 = E[|f(X)|].
\end{align}

I know $X_n$ in this example may not be considered as a strict "continuous random variable", but from measure theory perspective, it is continuous almost everywhere.  Besides, you can easily modify it to be strictly continuous by linear interpolating $(n^{-1}, \sqrt{n})$ and $(2n^{-1}, 0)$, say, and the result should still stand.

Comment: +1 For a continuous example, just let every $X_n$ and $X$ have a Student $t(p-1)$ distribution with $p\gt 2$ and use the same $f.$